# Moshe being called Moshe Rabbeinu

Tags: names, moshe-rabbeinu, provenance

We refer to Moshe as "Moshe Rabbeinu". (It's interesting about the avos as well that we say, for example, Avraham Avinu; however, I'll keep that for a separate question.)

When was the first time (and where is it written) that Moshe was referred to as "Moshe Rabbeinu"?

Comment: Every time? This morning I know I referred to him as Moshe Avdecha at least once in my Mussaf for Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: @DoubleAA see edit.

Comment: @DoubleAA I see it's already been edited however rather when speaking about Moshe people usually (or all the time say "Rabbeinu" as well.

Comment: @msh210 My reference to him as "Moshe" was to simply bring out the point more (and show the difference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search yields no results in the Mishna but one result in the Tosefta, namely Avoda Zara 3:19. However this is only true in the [Erfurt manuscript](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/272.pdf) (see the third to last line of the page numbered 0424 in the linked pdf (71 megabytes)), not the Vienna one, nor the original printed editions.

Comment: ...and a lot of times in Bavli too. I don't think anyone can point to really the _first_ time. It seems to have just been standard practice back then.

Comment: Do you think you could note, please, how many bytes that file is if that number is large, so unsuspecting people don't try downloading it on slow connections? (+1, incidentally.)

Comment: @msh210 It's about 74,673,075 bytes. That said, it really does say what I say it says :)

Comment: @DoubleAA - A lot of times in Bavli? Can you name at least one? And in regards to your answer we'll let R' Saul Liberman be the kava'ah on which girsa is right (thus helping to establish an earlier makor :)

Comment: @Yehoshua See Brachot 3b 7a 12b 32b 33b 34a 55a 61a. Instead of writing the rest, do you have any specific Masechet for me to include? Also, I don't think there is Tosefta Kepshuta on Nezikin and on.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. So we'll ask R' David HaLivni then...

Comment: @DoubleAA As far as I know he didn't write it past the three Bavos. However, he did write an earlier commentary on Tosefta called Tosefes Rish'onim ([this](http://www.massorti.com/IMG/pdf/liberman_tossefet_rishonim_2.pdf#page=190) is the link to Avodah Zarah ch. 3), but I couldn't find when he addresses it because I don't know the words surrounding "Rabbeinu" (I wasn't able to download the manuscript right now)

Comment: @ba It's right at the very very end of the perek. I don't see it discussed in your link.